# how to search LINQ SQL where value in LIST<object>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a SQL table called Quotes.

And in C# the user I have:

```
Public class Locations
{ 
 public string cityname { get; set; }
}

 List<Locations> = new puLocations List<Locations>  // Pickup Locations
 List<Locations> = new delLocations List<Locations> // Delivery Locations
```

Now I want to search my quote table with these lists.. something like this (obviously this doesnt work)

```
var quotes = from q in db.Quotes
where q.PULocations in puLocations  //puLocatiosn is the list<Locations>
and q.DELLocations in delLocations
select q;
```

so I want it to return ANY match.. ie If in pu locations i have gold coast, sydney, Brisbane. And Delivery location i have Perth, Hobart
it should return gold coast -> perth
 gold coast -> hobart
 sydney -> perth
 sydney -> gold coast 
.... etc (if those quotes exist)

Answer (score 2):

First you need this

```
List<Locations> puLocations= new  List<Locations>()  // Pickup Locations  
List<Locations> delLocations = new  List<Locations>() // Delivery Locations
```

And then you want to use the `.Contains()` extension method like :

```
var quotes = from q in db.Quotes where q.PULocations.Contains(puLocations) and 
q.DELLocations.Contains(delLocations) select q;
```

Comment: `Contains` is not a LINQ extension method; it has been there as long `List<T>` has.

Answer (score -1):

In order not to make your life harder you should make this operation in db, and i bet you have pickup and delivery locations in you database together with quotes
so supposing that you have them like `db.Locations.Where(l=>l.type==DEL)` and `db.Locations.Where(l=>l.type==PU)` you would write the following query

```
var quotes = from q in db.Quotes
    join del in db.Locations on del equals q.DELLocations
    join pu in db.Locations on pu equals q.PULocations
    where pu.type == PU && del.type == DEL && otherConditions
    select q;
```

also in case you really have constrains in you database they would propagate as navigation properties so you linq query would look like below

```
var quotes = from q in db.Quotes where q.DELLocation.field == something && q.PULocation.field == something
```

but you might have no constrain, so first query will be the way to go.

the last one way you can go is utilize Entity SQL `IN` statement, and write long statement like the following

```
   // you build string specifying as many parameters as you have items in your lists
   var entitySQL = "select quote FROM [Quotes] WHERE quote.DELLocation.LocationID IN (@delparam1, @delparam2,.... ) AND quote.PULocation.LocationID in (@puparam1, @puparam2,.... )"
   // then you create ObjectParameterCollection to substitute your IDs to ObjectQuery
   var opc = new ObjectParameterCollection();
   opc.Add("@delparam1", DELLocation[0].LocationID) // obviously you'll do it using linq
   opc.Add("@puparam1", PULocation[0].LocationID)

   // create object query

   var quotes = db.CreateQuery<Quote>(entitySQL, opc);
```